# Is there a way to declare TypeScript types on the same line as destructured properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I'm currently writing an `interface` which works alright, but is verbose. Declaring types in this manner adds around n+3 lines of code (n = number of props) and I tend to look up and down at the `interface` multiple times when working on this file, since the types are declared away from where the props are being destructured.

**Using an interface:**

```
interface MyComponentProps {
  name: String;
  type: String;
  minLength?: Number;
  maxLength?: Number;
}

function MyComponent({
  name = "",
  type = "text",
  minLength,
  maxLength,
  ...props
}: MyComponentProps) {
  return null;
}
```

I'm simply wondering if there's a way to declare types next to where the props are destructured, such as:

**Destructured types?**

```
function MyComponent({
  name, (String)
  type, (String)
  minLength, (Number?)
  maxLength, (Number?)
  ...props (any?)
}) {
  return null;
}
```

I apologize if this is obvious or has been asked previously, but I'm new to TypeScript and wasn't able to find any answers that didn't essentially just say: "Use an interface"

Comment: No, there is no way to do this because you're trying to mix runtime code with compile-time type definitions

Comment: You can inline the interface definition, but no there is no way to put the types in the destructuring pattern.